# Loopback custom method call from Android

Tags: android, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am looking for example where I can call loopback's custom method from Android. To explain more, lets say I have a method on server side with name "greet(name)" that will greet someone. I want to invoke that from Android. Any example, or link is ok.

Thanks in advance.

Jahid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the examples below, I'll assume your model is called `Greeter` and the static method `Greeter.greet` is invoked via `GET /greeters/greet?name=Alex`.

First of all, you need to describe the REST mapping of your method. Then you can call the method using `invokeMethod`.

```
public class GreeterRepository extends ModelRepository<Greeter> {
    public RestContract createContract() {
      RestContract contract = super.createContract();

      contract.addItem(new RestContractItem("/" + getNameForRestUrl() + "/greet", "POST"),
                  getClassName() + ".greet");

      return contract;
    }

    public void greet(name, final VoidCallback callback) {
        invokeStaticMethod("greet", ImmutableMap.of("name", name), new Adapter.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                callback.onError(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                callback.onSuccess();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See [ModelRepository.java](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/strongloop/android/loopback/ModelRepository.java) and [Model.java](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/strongloop/android/loopback/Model.java) for examples of methods that parse the response body.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of LoopBack, loopback-sdk-android is one of my specialisations.*

Comment: Thanks a lot Miroslav. Will be really nice if it is possible to have this in the documentation. Also a round-trip example someone where in the example folder of source code.

Comment: @JahidShohel could you please open a github issue to track your request? Please include a link to this SO thread and describe what else you would like to see in the docs. https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/issues/new

Comment: sure, will do sometime today

Comment: how can I achieve a similar behavior but for POST, not GET?

Comment: @JohnofArdeal the code should be similar. What did you try so far?

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš i tried the code from the response; the request makes its way to the server, but I haven't found a way to put data in the the request body

Comment: The second argument of `invokeStaticMethod` is called `params` and contains all data. Parameters that are present in the URL pattern are sent via the URL, all other parameters are send in the request body. See how Model.save() is implemented - https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/blob/714796513a8605eb531e77b8d15ad7a2cd61d788/src/main/java/com/strongloop/android/loopback/Model.java#L101

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš I want to send a post request with loopback "invokeStaticMethod". Please help me how to do it.
What I want: I want to send a api request http://localhost:3000/api/user/id/unblock
With parameter {"userId", "blockId"}
Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone please post a new question and show what have you tried so far.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš, Here it is. Please check the query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492305/loopback-post-method-call

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš, I've created a new question for this, Please check that  asap and help me here. Thanks in advance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492305/loopback-post-method-call